# Glowing the time in iPhone programming?

Tags: iphone, graphics, glow

[image]

How can I get the Glow like in Image, I need proper guide, I tried a lot, but it is glowing but not as it is shown in picture. 
please help

Comment: This question has been already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420131/iphone-text-glow-effect

Comment: I saw, but is making glow label so heavy, If I do rotate, then it will slow down rotation animation ....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2010/04/29/create-glow-soft-shadow-text-on-iphone/ . The screenshot looks quite similar to what you are trying to achieve (albeit a different color).

Comment: But if you will object then show time then seconds will now work properly, program will become heavy, i tried this, it is not siutable for me