# How to create a glowing font?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I would like to know how to create a glowing font that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420131/iphone-text-glow-effect

Comment: I didn't try anything yet.

Comment: Use a shadow and rather than using a black color or gray color use the color of the 'glow' you want..

Comment: @Ziad.T if you have not tried anything yet, why are you asking for help? Maybe try searching first? Hence the downvotes

Answer (score 2):

Try this tutorial, it includee the source as well, you might find it helpful

http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2010/04/29/create-glow-soft-shadow-text-on-iphone/

Answer (score 2):

The effects on the font in your example are almost certainly achieved with images. They most likely used Photoshop to create the images, and then they programmatically add and remove subviews as needed to display the digits, days of the week, etc.