# xcode UILabel text add outer glow effect

Tags: xcode, uilabel, effects, effect

How would I add an outer glow effect to a text of a UILabel. I tried to use the layer.shadow... properties but they are really just for a drop shadow.

```
_count.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_count.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
_count.layer.shadowOpacity = .8;
_count.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
_count.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
_count.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPhone Text Glow Effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420131/iphone-text-glow-effect)

Comment: I wasn't able to get an outer glow effect using those techniques.

Comment: mmm Your code works fine ... Check this [link](http://benscheirman.com/2011/09/creating-a-glow-effect-for-uilabel-and-uibutton/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I determined there was no way to put this kind effect on text there are ways to do an inner glow or a drop shadow as mentioned in the question but no way (that I can find) to add an outer glow to text. I ended up adding a png behind the text to complete a similar (yet not exactly what I was looking for) effect.